# How to selectively prevent Safari / Keychain from updating passwords?

Tags: safari, password, keychain, monterey

Safari 16, macOS Monterey 12.6

I have an interesting problem with Safari and the mechanism it uses when prompting to save a Website's password.

I use 2FA when logging onto a certain account, for which the standard userid and password are stored in the Keychain. Normally this is accessed with Touch-Id on the Mac. Following that the Website prompts me for my one-time password, generated from my 2FA app. The problem then lies with Safari seeing the OTP field on the page as another password to be stored, and because it is obviously different and single use, sees it as a change for the main credentials for the page, and so prompts me to store the 'new' password. Only by diligence and making sure I click 'No' when prompted have I been able to avoid inconvenience!

I have been burnt in the past by this behaviour on other websites, where Safari sees a 2FA code sent by SMS as a change, and I must admit I've idly clicked through, only to find my error next time I logon, leading to a tedious 'forgotten your password?' exchange.

Is there a way to lock change, say in the Keychain Access app? Is it due to the way secure fields on the page are recognised?

Small edit:

I noticed after a secondary search that switching off Autofill will prevent saving in addition to autofill, but I want to *allow* autofill, but *selectively stop* saving prompting.

Comment: Autofill isn't really for passwords - sure, it will sometimes remember a passworded entry [one remarkable case for that is my bank account, which *really* shouldn't] but auto-fill is insecure. I would take a guess that it's the site presenting fields incorrectly, which causes Safari to confuse 2FA with a password. I see some sites where it can't recognise the 2FA straight out of the SMS, others where it all works just as intended… & my bank, which will not save any password [correct behaviour based on old protocols, fine these days with fingerprints] yet stores it in auto-fill [dozy behaviour]

Comment: Yeah, I've had odd behaviour like that myself, where a hidden digit (please enter the 1st and 3rd...) of my Bank PIN (entered in addition to my password) is seen as a 'new password'. It's not offering to save the PIN, but thinks it's a new password. At least autofill is still subject to Touch-ID authentication. I wish auto store was as well.

Comment: Ah, yes - I'd forgotten the old 'first & third' thing. What a pita that was ;) At one point my bank insisted I access them through some 3rd party 'security' app. I wrote an actual ink letter asking why I should trust something I'd never heard of, based in another country. They removed the requirement ;)

Comment: I've just discovered the worst of this - setting up a new email domain & set of users in web forms. It stupidly can't tell the difference between 'new password' & 'new user' so I now have them all written in plaintext until I've finished the setup - then I can delete the excess.